# Error with Twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm trying to make a twitter web app on rails that can post and search for keywords and I can't figure out why it's not working, I've changed a thousand things and got a thousand different errors, this is my controller file

```
def hello
    @time = Time.now

def user_tweet
      require "rubygems"
      require "twitter"

    # Certain methods require authentication. To get your Twitter OAuth credentials,
    # register an app at http://dev.twitter.com/apps
    Twitter.configure do |config|
      config.consumer_key       = 'xxxx'
      config.consumer_secret    = 'xxxx'
      config.oauth_token        = 'xxxx'
      config.oauth_token_secret = 'xxxx'
    end

     # Initialize your Twitter client
     client = Twitter::Client.new
     # Post a status update
     client.update("updated tweet")
     redirect_to request.referer, :notice => 'Tweet successfully posted'
   end
```

end

and this is my view page

```
 <%= form_for (@tweet = Tweet.new, :url => user_tweet_path) do |tweet_form| 
 tweet_form.text_area :tweet_content, :id => "tweet" 
 tweet_form.submit "Tweet" 
 end  %>
```

Finally, here's the error I'm getting:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

I tried just putting `<%= client.update("updated tweet")%>` in the view file but it raised an undefined variable error, I'm new to rails, so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Got a stack trace for that error?

Answer (score 0):

For style, close your ERB tags after every line, don't put spaces after parentheses (like the `form_for` above) and don't assing values to `@tweet` (you don't need it):

```
<%= form_for(Tweet.new, :url => user_tweet_path) do |tweet_form| %>              
  <%= tweet_form.text_area :tweet_content, :id => "tweet" %> 
  <%= tweet_form.submit "Tweet"  %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now it says "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Tweet" although as you can sees in my controller,  I initialized with "client = Twitter::Client.new" I'm not sure what I'm missing, any ideas?

Comment: That means that you don't have a model called Tweet so you need to create one before using it in the template with `form_for`.